# Cutting off polygon splinters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, editing, cut-fill

There is an analysis about the potential of solar areas in Germany. When I finished the project I realised, that there is one polygon with a huge value for its area. By looking closer it gets clear that this one geometry includes nearly 100 *"splinters"* all over the study area.

[image]

What I want to do is to cut off and remove all superfluous parts/splinters. It would be best if its possible to sort out by area of the splinters.

Comment: Select the polygon, `Multipart to singleparts` (Only selected features), in the new layer calculate the area of each feature, delete those smaller than a certain value.

Comment: Or add a calculated field to the layer showing the area of each feature. Then set the layer query to only show features with a chosen minimum area. That way, you don't lose the splinters if you make a mistake. Just change the query.